# Web page not available when trying to open payment links - Ionic/Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor, instamojo

In my Ionic App I'm trying to integrate payment gateway. Below is my function

```
openInAppBrowser() {
    this.shosHide = true;
    
    this.http.get(`${this.settings.createPaymentRequest}?MOBILE=${this.diverDetails.phoneNumber.replace('+91','')}&EMAIL=${this.diverDetails.email}&NAME=${this.diverDetails.displayName}&AMOUNT=${this.amountForm.get('amount').value}&UID=${this.diverDetails.uid}`).subscribe(res => {
      if (res['STATUS'] === 'SUCCESS') {
        window.location.href = res['RESPONSE'].longurl;
      }

    });
  }
```

Now In my android app,

[image]

If use selects any of the UPI payment method, I'm getting the below error.

[image]

In Android Mainfest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
        android:name="com.car2godroptaxi.driverapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
</application>
```